# URI::InvalidURIError: Carrierwave s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload my files to S3 via carrierwave but getting a `URI::InvalidURIError` error.

What is strange is I am seeing in my logs fog: followed redirect to `MYBUCKETNAME.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. This naming seems wrong. Did I enter in the config variables wrong below?

Two lines down I am also seeing

Excon::Errors::SocketError (hostname `"MYBUCKETNAME.MYBUCKETNAME.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"` does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)):

**carrierwave.rb**

```
unless ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'].blank?

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp') # adding these...
config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave' # ...two lines

config.fog_credentials = {
  provider:              'AWS',                        # required
  aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                        # required
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],                        # required
  region:                'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']                          # required
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"


#for fog
config.fog_public = false
 end
end
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by adding the following to my config/carrierwave.rb file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
end
```